# How do I capture individuals speaking in a 75' X 50' space?

Tags: microphone, crowd

At our place of worship, we are doing a hybrid In Person / Zoom Sunday School.  We are currently using our condenser mics to pick up questions from the "In Person" crowd.

The issue is, we are not fully capturing the audio and amplifying it enough so that the Zoom participants can clearly hear the "In Person" crowd questions.  We are trying to keep individuals social distant and keep from passing a mic around for questions, because of Covid.

What is the best mic to use and mic array for a 75' X 50' area?  We have a Behringer X32 Producer with 6 spare inputs.

Comment: You mean, other than hire a boom op?

Comment: We have a similar issue in my church. Pre-COVID passing round a (radio) mic gave much better sound. For COVID perhaps you could have someone hold the mic on a boom so individuals don't need to touch it. This might also allow you to have a consistent spacing between the speaker and the mic, which varies widely when people hold the mic themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible to do this well in venues that are not custom designed (such as modern meeting rooms with sound treatment) - and even then it is very expensive for any large space such as the area you have, which is why the majority of events and venues use roaming mics or boom mics, and the presenter should always repeat the question for the benefit of the audience.

Boom operators require a fair bit of space but can be very quick at getting a mic to where it is needed and staying out the way of your attendees.

Roaming mics require runners, and a certain amount of audience participation to get them to where they need to be quickly, but are cheap, convenient, and can be used for multiple purposes. They may be a concern right now, as @GrahamNye mentioned, because of the potential for Covid transmission.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy. Probably not very good. I would try by setting up a number of mics spaced around the room, the more the better. Perhaps hanged from the ceiling. The mixer operator would need to select the closest mic depending on the speaker (more mics makes it more difficult for the mixer operator) .